# hashCode() and equals() methods of a composite id class

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, equals, hashcode

It's been days I'm trying to find the correct way to implement the equals() and hashCode() methods of a composite-id class.

The trouble I'm facing when I try to update the main object (Gara) are:

1. StackOverflow
2. DuplicateKeyException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
3. org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists

My Composite-id class

```
@Embeddable 
public class GaraAgenziaId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4934033367128755763L;

    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GaraAgenziaId.class);

    private Gara gara;

    private Agenzia agenzia;

    @ManyToOne
    public Gara getGara() {
        return gara;
    }

    public void setGara(Gara gara) {
        this.gara = gara;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Agenzia getAgenzia() {
        return agenzia;
    }

    public void setAgenzia(Agenzia agenzia) {
        this.agenzia = agenzia;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GaraAgenziaId [Gara=" + gara + ", agenzia=" + agenzia
                + "]";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

these seems to work very well:

```
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this== o) return true;
        if (o ==null|| getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        GaraAgenziaId that = (GaraAgenziaId) o;

        if (gara !=null?!gara.equals(that.gara) : that.gara !=null) return false;
        if (agenzia !=null?!agenzia.equals(that.agenzia) : that.agenzia !=null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        result = (agenzia !=null? agenzia.hashCode() : 0);
        result =31* result + (gara !=null? gara.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't `31*a + b ` risk overflowing?

Comment: @Mindwin sorry but I'm not expert enought so I can't answer you. It was a piece of code found somewhere and it was working for my purpose

Comment: It will overflow, but without error, so it will still be effective as a hashcode.

Comment: @IanRobertson First, thanks a lot for your comment. But I was only able to see your reply by sheer luck (I was reviewing my starred list). Remember to @ quote!! XD